# Mercurial "default-push not found!"?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I have Mercurial installed on my Windows 7 machine. I know this because when I type `hg --version` I get:

```
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.5.2)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2012 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I just committed some code to a local repo via `hg commit -m "Made some changes."`.

I then type `hg push` and get:

```
pushing to default-push
abort: repository default-push not found!
```

My `C:\Users\myuser\.hg\hgrc` file looks like:

```
[trusted]
users = myuser
```

**What's going on here?**

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Its not a dupe, shows effort/research, and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I don't mind downvotes, but would like to know why this is a bad question.

Answer (score 6):

You need to configure your default path. You do this by having a section like this in the `.hg\hgrc` file:

```
[paths]
default = http://somewhere/to/push/to
```

The `default` path will be used for both `hg push` and `hg pull`. You can also configure a `default-push` path if you would like to use a different path for `hg push`. See [`hg help paths`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths) for more help on this.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Geisler (+1) - I tried this and it didn't work. I ended up just re-cloning my remote repo to a different location on my file system and this worked. hg is for the birds